# Error Converting an XML File to an Excel File

Tags: excel, xslt

I get the following error when I try to convert an XML file using XSLT to an Excel file:

> XML ERROR in Table
>   REASON:    Bad Value
>   FILE:  C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\TEMPOR~1\Content.MSO\B7F7687D.xls
>   GROUP: Cell
>   TAG:   Data
>   VALUE: 03/17/2011

Comment: My crystal ball is out of order - please provide the xsl - otherwise there is no way to tell.

Comment: If it isn't too large, you should also post your xml

Comment: Both are actually irrelevant, the problem is in the XML that's generated. I've been doing this exact same thing just recently.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've probably not set the type of the cell's data correctly (`ss:Type`).
You need to be generating something along the lines of

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
  <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2011-03-17T00:00:00.000</Data>
</Cell>
```

and also set a style ID for the Cell id:

```
<Style ss:ID="s1">
  <NumberFormat ss:Format="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
</Style>
```

Or failing that, you can just set the ss:Type to 'String' if it doesn't need to actually contain a date value.